# Tkinter Box Model

Tags: python, css, user-interface, tkinter

I am using tkinter as a gui framework for a python application.

Now my design department asked me to adapt to our corporate design, so I tried to create all necessary tkinter elements in the correct design. Therefore I wrapped each element in three frames to represent the box-model from css (padding, border, margin). This also lets me create asymmetrical variants as needed.

When ironing out smaller bugs in the adaptation I encountered great problems for any clickable element, as the padding and border are still part of the element and need to respond to mouse interaction such as hover or click. Also I was unable to reuse already combined elements such as a option menu, as I found no way to edit each sub-element (entry, button, list).

Therefore I was wondering, if there are any existing implementations of the box model for tkinter already done or if there is a purpose in trying to polish my draft.

I am glad for any bits and pieces that guide me in a expedient direction, even if it's not what I intended by asking this question :)

Comment: I think you would be better off understanding tkinter's geometry manager,than to try to implement the css box model with tkinter. The latter sounds like a tremendous amount of work.  Widgets already have padding and borders, and to wrap each widget in three separate frames seems excessive.

Comment: As far as I understand the geometry manager of tkinter, it is pretty limited in what it can do. To my knowledge I can, for example, not control different sides of padding and border individually, which would be a deal-breaker for my requirements. Additionally some elements use different units to measure their height (pixels vs font lines), which can be overcome by using frames instead.

Comment: _"As far as I understand the geometry manager of tkinter, it is pretty limited in what it can do. "_ - I disagree. Perhaps your needs are extremely unique, but in my nearly three decades using the tk library I've not found any layout problems that I couldn't solve. Yes, sometimes it involves using extra frames, but certainly not always.